# Can't take data from textfield by getText() in java

Tags: java, javafx

I am using javafx to take input from two text field and after validating it I want to switch scene. I have tried `getText()` method to take data from text field. But its not working.I can't find out my fault.Can anyone help please? here is my code.

```
String checkid = "project";
String checkpass = "aritra";

Label userid = new Label("User ID");

grid.setConstraints(userid,0,2);
TextField idinput = new TextField();
idinput.setPromptText("ID");
idinput.getText();
grid.setConstraints(idinput,1,2,2,1);

String id = idinput.getText().toString();

Label passlabel = new Label("Password");
grid.setConstraints(passlabel,0,3);

TextField passinput = new TextField();
passinput.setPromptText("password");
passinput.getText();
grid.setConstraints(passinput,1,3,2,1);

String pass= passinput.getText().toString();

Button login =new Button("Connect");
grid.setConstraints(login,1,4);
grid.getChildren().
addAll(text,userid,idinput,passlabel,passinput,login);

scene1 = new Scene(grid,600,500);
window.setScene(scene1);

login.setOnAction(e->{
    if(!passinput.getText().isEmpty() && 
        !idinput.getText().isEmpty()){
            System.out.printf("id %s", id);
            System.out.printf("pass %s", pass);
            if(id.equals(checkid)&& pass.equals(checkpass)){
                window.setScene(scene2);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Not matched");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: You're calling `getText()` on the text field immediately after creating it. Surely this will just give you an empty string. Why don't you just do `String id = idinput.getText();` in the event handler?

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. :)